# findByIdAndUpdate not updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

When I test my update route in postman the server gives me a status code of 200 but nothing updated in my database, why is it not updating?

```
exports.updateTodos = async (req, res, next)=>{
    try{
        const update = await Todos.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id});
        res.send({
            success: true,
            todosData: update,
            Msg: "successfully updated!"
        }).status(200);
    }catch(error){
        res.send({
            success: false,
            Msg: "There was A problem updating to todos",
            err: error
        });
    }
}

//This is my schema data
const schema = mongoose.Schema({
    task: {
        type: String,
        maxlength: 300,
        require: true
    },
    taskname: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        maxlength: 14
    },
    createAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

this is how I call updateTodos in my router

```
router.put('/:id', updateTodos);
```

Comment: How is `updateTodos` called in your router?

Comment: What error do you get? @WilliamKolee

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett that's the thing I'm not getting any errors, in fact, I get a status code 200 telling me the request was successful but the problem here is I'm not seeing any update in my database, that values are still the same.

Comment: See answer below @WilliamKolee

Comment: @Phix router.put('/:id', updateTodos);

Comment: @William in your code I noticed you are not sending any data to update, you are only calling the update function 
Your
`const update = await Todos.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id});`

But 
`const update = await Todos.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: req.body});`

Answer (score 1):

You're basically not setting anything to be updated. See how it is done below

```js
exports.updateTodos = async (req, res, next)=>{
    try{
        const update = await Todos.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: req.body});
        res.send({
            success: true,
            todosData: update,
            Msg: "successfully updated!"
        }).status(200);
    }catch(error){
        res.send({
            success: false,
            Msg: "There was A problem updating to todos",
            err: error
        });
    }
}
```

You can also explicitly choose what to update like so:

```js
exports.updateTodos = async (req, res, next)=>{
    try{
        const update = await Todos.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, 
                            {$set: {taskname: req.body.taskname}});
        res.send({
            success: true,
            todosData: update,
            Msg: "successfully updated!"
        }).status(200);
    }catch(error){
        res.send({
            success: false,
            Msg: "There was A problem updating to todos",
            err: error
        });
    }
}
```